# named parameters in database/sql and database/sql/driver

Tags: sql, database, go, neo4j, driver

I'm trying to figure out what the pattern is for using named parameters in go's built-in database/sql package. I looked at the oracle driver, but it seems like just a wrapper for the C library. Have people solved this in an elegant way? So far I've just worked around the problem by putting `{0}`, `{1}` as the parameters in the unit tests, but it sure would be nice to be able to use them normally as a `map[string]interface{}` or something. Does anyone have an idea or an implementation that seems idiomatic?

For reference, here is a test:

```
db := testConn()
stmt, err := db.Prepare("return {0} as int1, {1} as int2")
if err != nil {
   t.Fatal(err)
}
rows, err := stmt.Query(123, 456)
if err != nil {
   t.Fatal(err)
}
rows.Next()

var test int
var test2 int
err = rows.Scan(&test, &test2)
if err != nil {
   t.Fatal(err)
}
if test != 123 {
   t.Fatal("test != 123;", test)
}
if test2 != 456 {
   t.Fatal("test2 != 456;", test2)
}
```

And what I'm doing in `Query` is:

```
func (stmt *cypherStmt) Query(args []driver.Value) (driver.Rows, error) {
   cyphReq := cypherRequest{
      Query: stmt.query,
   }
   if len(args) > 0 {
      cyphReq.Params = make(map[string]interface{})
   }
   for idx, e := range args {
      cyphReq.Params[strconv.Itoa(idx)] = e
   }
...
```

Comment: The existing answers seem to assume that you're writing a client, but it looks to me like you're writing a driver. Is that right?

Comment: Yep: https://github.com/wfreeman/cq

Comment: The database/sql package is built around positional parameters, not named parameters. So any workaround to make it use named parameters would be unidiomatic almost by definition.

Comment: I'm coming to that realization. It's been a month since I started the project. Still, the query language implemented uses named parameters (and that's the idiomatic way). The main problem with implementation is that they need to be pushed through the driver.Value type, as opposed to interface{}.

Comment: I don't know what's exactly behind that `db.Prepare` method, but as far as I undestand, you are trying to create an SQL query object and add paramenters in OO manner, so you can pass values to be used in `WHERE` clause (as an example). There is a stored procedure in MS SQL called `sp_executesql` that can take SQL statement with parameters' values marked by placeholders, and then populate defined parameters' values from variables. Oracle should have the same thing. If this is at all close to what your are looking for, I can have a look further into this.

Comment: I'm looking for a go database/sql/driver implementation that allows the use of named parameters in a driver somehow.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/vmihailenco/pg which doesn't use database/sql behind it. Might help.

Comment: Yeah, I was really hoping to get by with database/sql. I have looked at that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to create a `map[string]interface{}` type that implements `driver.Valuer{}` to serialize it as a `[]byte`, and then convert it back in the driver.

But that would be inefficient and unidiomatic. Since your driver would then be used in a nonstandard way anyway, it would probably be better to just forget about database/sql and write a package with a totally custom interface.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using wrapper on top of database/sql called sqlx
https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx
You can check here how he did it.

Example on how to select into a tuple

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `db:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `db:"last_name"`
    Email     string
}
jason = Person{}
err = db.Get(&jason, "SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name=$1", "Jason")
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", jason)
// Person{FirstName:"Jason", LastName:"Moiron", Email:"jmoiron@jmoiron.net"}
```

Example on how to insert a tuple

```
dude := Person{
    FirstName:"Jason", 
    LastName:"Moiron", 
    Email:"jmoiron@jmoiron.net"
}
 _, err = db.NamedExec(`INSERT INTO person (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES (:first,:last,:email)`, dude)
```

Comment: My question is kind of reverse--how to put parameters in as a map.

Comment: I've edited a question with a details on how to insert a tuple

Comment: Cool--I'm still hoping for someone to show a way with the native database/sql package.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no driver natively provides for named parameters.  I personally use [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp) which allows you to bind queries from structs or maps:

```
_, err = dbm.Select(&users,
    "select * from PersistentUser where mykey = :Key",
    map[string]interface{}{
        "Key": 43,
    }
)
```

or

```
_, err = dbm.Select(&users,
    "select * from PersistentUser where mykey = :Key",
    User{Key: 43},
)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning--that's pretty slick. I'm hoping for a way with the native database/sql package.

Comment: You cannot do it with native database/sql